# RabbitMQ user authorization to read queues but prevent purge access

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I added a user in RabbitMQ and edited the permissions to read ".*" in the RabbitMQ admin console.

The output of the command `list_permissions` shows that the user "readman" only has read permissions.

```
$ rabbitmqctl list_permissions --vhost /
Listing permissions for vhost "/" ...
user    configure       write   read
admin          .*      .*      .*
guest           .*      .*      .*
readman                         .*
```

However, I can still purge messages from the queue when logged in as "readman". Is this expected? How can I enable an user to view the queues and messages, but not to purge the queues's messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is expected , since as per the permission table the amqp ( 0-9-1 ) operation for `queue.purge` requires only **READ** permission on the queue , so any user who has a read permission on a queue will be able to purge that queue as well.

[image]

Comment: let me add link to the docs with this table https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#authorisation

Comment: discussion with RabbitMQ authors explaining why read for purge here https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions/10076

Comment: Thanks @bedla.czech , for sharing additional information , yes once something get's established then it is hard to change it ... "you don't fix what ain't broke"